# Android why onReceive() does not work

Tags: java, android, sms

I have a class for receiving sms:

```
package com.example.app;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: ");
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                    // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                            "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.app;

        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: ");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name=
                        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

The method onReceive doesn't executes. I can see it in logs (no logs). I am sending sms through telnet - emulator receives sms but app not. Why ? What's wrong ?

Comment: Why is receiver inside Activity tag?

Comment: move `<receiver>...</receiver>` tag outside `</activity>` tag

Comment: it should be inside application tag!

Comment: Thank you, I have moved outside activity tag and works ! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html
*receiver* is contained inside *application* node. Move it out of *activity*

Answer (score 0):

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("IntentTag");
registerReceiver(new SmsReceiver(), filter);
```

Comment: Well he said it worked with moving the receiver out of the activity tag while i was wondering how a receiver works without registering it. Guess the case only required when you want to register a receiver from a service.